# Frida SharedPreferences hooking problem - how can I get the filename and path

Tags: javascript, android, hook, frida, dynamic-analysis

I have an app I want to analyze with Frida. The app has over 20 different shared preferences XML files. I am hooking the put methods of the shared preferences like in this code snippet:

```
var sp = Java.use("android.app.SharedPreferencesImpl$EditorImpl");
sp.putString.implementation = function(var0, var1) {
console.log(var0 + " " + var1 + "\n");
return this.putString(var0, var1);
}
```

This class has no method like getPath() or similar. How can I add code into this hooked method, to receive the correct xml file? When I use *getSharedPreferences* from *android.content.ContextWrapper* it does not work, because the app uses so many xml files that I can not tell, where the written info belongs to.

I tried out to hook variables and methods from SharedPreferencesImpl. I tried to get the mfile which is an java.io.File object, but I could not make it to call the getPath() method from the file object. I also tried to hook several methods in SharedPreferencesImpl but it does not work. I am also not sure if this is the right way.

Comment: This exceeds my programming skills. Do you may have an example?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can simply get the file name where the string is written to is applied on this way:

```
var sp = Java.use("android.app.SharedPreferencesImpl$EditorImpl");
sp.putString.implementation = function (key, value) {
    console.log(`putString("${key}", "${value}")`);

    let outer = this.this$0.value; // SharedPreferencesImpl 
    console.log("pref file: " + outer.mFile.value);

    return this.putString(key, value);
}
```

#### How to build to this code

`android.app.SharedPreferencesImpl$EditorImpl` is a non-static inner class of `android.app.SharedPreferencesImpl`. This means that every `$EditorImpl` instance has a reference to it's outer class `SharedPreferencesImpl`.

You won't see this field in the [source code of those classes](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/base/+/master/core/java/android/app/SharedPreferencesImpl.java) as it is an implicit reference generated by the compiler. So when the Java code is compiled the compiler adds a parameter to all constructors of the inner class and generates to save this value in a special field in the inner class.

You can get a list of all fields of `EditorImpl` in the frida console by executing the following two commands:

```
var sp = Java.use("android.app.SharedPreferencesImpl$EditorImpl");
sp.class.getDeclaredFields().forEach(f => console.log(f))
```

You will get a list of fields, including this one:

```
final android.app.SharedPreferencesImpl android.app.SharedPreferencesImpl$EditorImpl.this$0
```

So we now know the field name of the outer class is `this$0` - if we are in the Frida hooking code of `putString` we can get the outer class by reading `this.this$0.value`.

From here to the value of `mFile`, where the `File` is stored in we are interested in, it is just a small step:

```
this.this$0.value.mFile.value;
```